# Python pymysql works but sqlalchemy not working

Tags: python, pymysql

```
local_port=ssh_tunnel.local_bind_port
URL = f"mysql+pymysql://db_user:db_pwd@127.0.0.1:{local_port}"
    engine = create_engine(URL, echo=True)  
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(text("SELECT * FROM <table_name>"))
```

2023-08-16 11:36:27,708 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2023-08-16 11:36:27,710 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_password=ssh_password,
        remote_bind_address=(mysql_host, mysql_port)
) as tunnel:

    # Create SQLAlchemy engine using SSH tunnel
    db_url = f"mysql+pymysql://{mysql_user}:{mysql_password}@{tunnel.local_bind_host}:{tunnel.local_bind_port}"
    engine = create_engine(db_url)

    # Execute the MySQL query
    query = "SELECT * FROM <table_name>;"
    result = engine.execute(query).fetchall()

print(result)
```

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11529/40324251.py in 
     28     # Execute the MySQL query
     29     query = "SELECT * FROM global_variables;"
---> 30     result = engine.execute(query).fetchall()
     31 
     32 print(result)

 in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)

~/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py in warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    466         if not skip_warning:
    467             _warn_with_version(message, version, wtype, stacklevel=3)
--> 468         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    469 
    470     doc = func.__doc__ is not None and func.__doc__ or ""

~/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   3254 
   3255         """
-> 3256         connection = self.connect(close_with_result=True)
   3257         return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
   3258 
...
-> 2458         if self._is_mysql and self.server_version_info >= (5, 7, 20):
   2459             cursor.execute("SELECT @@transaction_isolation")
   2460         else:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: i have attached above please check

Comment: That is not the stacktrace. Please provide all the text in the console before the TypeError.

Comment: could you please check now added stacktrace

Comment: The error is very explicit. The variable self.server_version_info is None, thus the comparison fails. You either modified it yourself or your installation has a problem.